# Is it possible to change the font in cmd for one app and retain the default font for other programs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, fonts, text-editors

I want to change the default font for a console text editor I am using on Windows. Looking on the internet, it seems I need to change cmd's font by right-clicking the title bar. However, that changes the font for all programs that use cmd. I want to change the font only for the Text editor, and retain the default font for other apps. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a shortcut of CMD and then set the settings on exactly that shortcut. Right click properties. So you have the changed font / font-color settings only for that shortcut and retain the default setting for the other ways of opening CMD (e.g. startmenu, run dialog, etc.). But I'm not sure if this sufficiently answers your question.

[image]

PS.: Sorry it's the German properties dialog but it should work the same for the English version.